# How to add navigation to backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, navigation

A simple issue, but can't remember how to do it best. What I want is to automatically send the user to another page `"/lecturer/marking/marking-section-two"` after a code section is run.

Is there a way of doing this in the backing bean that won't effect the ajax message displayed before it ?

This is the code i am running

```
public void markSectionOne() {
    //supposing the data in markSectionOne is filled...
    this.markingFacade.create(markSectionOne);
    this.setMessage("Mark Saved");
    //after saving...
    markSectionOne = new Marking();
    // now navigating to the next page
}
```

and once it's run I want to navigate automatically to a new page.

Thanks guys

Comment: Change method signature to `public String markSectionOne()` and return redirection outcome. Outcome can be registered in **faces-config.xml** in section `<navigation-rule>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your method to return a String which will be interpreted as the next navigation outcome.

```
public String markSectionOne() {
    // ... unrelevant code
    return "/lecturer/marking/marking-section-two";
}
```

If the method returns `null`, then JSF will stay on the same page.

Comment: Thanks :) i wasn't sure if changing the method to return a string would effect the functionality of it, thanks a lot :)